# PySpark to PMML - Failed to build PMML file

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

Currently, I am working on a simple machine learning program that generates a PMML.
For this experiment, I use PySpark as machine learning library and pyspark2pmml as PMML builder.

I have a problem when I want to build a PMML file.
All the process from data loading until training model was no problem. However, **I was unable to generate a pmml file with the transformed data from previous steps.**

```py
... (previous steps)

filtered_data = filtered_data.filter(data['year'] <= '2020')

cat_cols = ['CYC_CLASS', 'CYC_DISCHPORT']
num_cols = ['weekofyear']
label_cols = 'dwell_time'

# replace column names
replacements = {c:c.replace(c, 'pre_' + c) for c in filtered_data.columns if c in cat_cols}
filtered_df = filtered_data.select([col(c).alias(replacements.get(c, c)) for c in filtered_data.columns])

# prepare string indexer
si = [StringIndexer(inputCol='pre_' + d, outputCol=d, handleInvalid='keep') for d in cat_cols]
feat_cols = [d for d in cat_cols] + num_cols
print(feat_cols)

# create pipeline: indexing data into string index
pipeline_si = Pipeline(stages=si)
pipeline_si_data = pipeline_si.fit(filtered_df)

# transform data using string indexer
indexed_data = pipeline_si_data.transform(filtered_df)
indexed_data = indexed_data.select([label_cols] + feat_cols)
indexed_data.show(5)

# define and concat features columns
formula = RFormula(formula = "dwell_time ~ .")

# prepare classifier: we don't define featuresCol here, we will use Rformula instead !
dt_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(maxBins=10)

# create pipeline: training classifier using training data
classififer_pipeline = Pipeline(stages =[formula, dt_clf])
dts_model = classififer_pipeline.fit(indexed_data)
print(dts_model)
```

Code for exporting to PMML file:

```py
from pyspark2pmml import PMMLBuilder
pmmlDTs = PMMLBuilder(spark, indexed_data, dts_model)
pmmlDTs.buildFile("test_dtsi_22121230556.pmml")
```

and I got the error [image]

Interestingly, when I convert `indexed_data` into CSV file then load it back as DataFrame, I can generate a PMML file.

```py
# prepare data
test_df = spark.read.csv('indexed.csv', header=True, inferSchema = True)

# define and concat features columns
formula = RFormula(formula = "dwell_time ~ .")

# prepare classifier: we don't define featuresCol here, we will use Rformula instead !
dt_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(maxBins=10)

# create pipeline: training classifier using training data
classififer_pipeline = Pipeline(stages =[formula, dt_clf])
dts_model = classififer_pipeline.fit(test_df)
print(dts_model)

pmmlDTs = PMMLBuilder(spark, test_df, dts_model)
pmmlDTs.buildFile("test_dtsi_22121230556www.pmml")

out: 
'D:\\MYWORLD\\CODE\\pmml\\test_dtsi_22121230556www.pmml'
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is my mistake in the first approach? and What is the difference with second approach? Since I am new at using PySpark.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to figure out what is my mistake in the first approach?

Your conceptual mistake is that you're applying the `RFormula` transformation to an indexed data.

The main value proposition of `RFormula` is that it will inspect the type of incoming columns (eg. continuous vs. categorical), and perform any essential transformations automatically (eg. keeping continuous columns as-is vs. applying string indexing to all categorical columns).

Right now, the `RFormula` transformation is probably attempting to apply a "second layer" of string indexing to categorical columns. The PMML converter analyzes the pipeline model, and finds this sequence of operations non-sensical, and hence bails out with an exception.

> What is the difference with second approach?

When you save your doubly string-indexed data into a CSV file, and load it back from there, then you get a different data schema.

The CSV file likely contains all-numeric columns, and the new CSV data schema probably declares that the pipeline is dealing with all continuous columns now.